# Is there any way to assign a vector to another and then sort it in R

Tags: r

```
    heights = c(154,152,165,160)
    names(heights) = c("Dan","Gan","Tan","Ban")


    n=length(heights)
    for(j in c(1:n))
    {
     for(i in c(1:(n-1)))
     {
      if(heights[i]>heights[i+1])
      {
       c=heights[I]
       heights[i]=heights[i+1]
       heights[i+1]=c
      }
     }
    }
    print(heights)
```

#I want to sort the vector of names according to the ascending
order of heights (from shorter to higher).

Answer (score 0):

The `order` function provides an argsort functionality, so that

```
names(heights)[order(heights)]
```

should give you what you want

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `sort()`?

```
sort(heights) |>
    names()

[1] "Gan" "Dan" "Ban" "Tan"
```